# What could be an example of a sequence of real numbers such that every x∈[0,1] is an accumulation point of this sequence?

Tags: general-topology

I'm searching for a sequence of real numbers such that every $x\in[0,1]$ is an accumulation point of this sequence, and right now I'm thinking ${1\over2}\sin(n)+{1\over2}$, but I have no idea how to prove this, nor whether this sequence is appropriate. So any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your sine example probably works, but is way too hard to prove at this level. I don't know what order you've covered things in, but think about the fact that the image of the sequence is countable, but still close to every number in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Just take any enumeration of the rationals in $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One example: Write the sequence of all the natural numbers in base 2. Do not omit writing the decimal point. Hold this to a mirror to see a L-R reversal. In the mirror is a sequence of all numbers in (0,1) that have binary representations with only finitely many 1's in them.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a countable set can be written in a sequence. Now remember that there is a very canonical countable set which is dense in $[0,1]$.